# INSERT INTO between tables with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, civicrm

An earlier data import in CiviCRM placed some member numbers into a custom field (`member_number`) instead of the more useful (`external_id`) field.

My (admittedly limited) SQL skills are way too rusty, but what I'm trying to do is:

1. IF `external_id` field is empty,
2. AND the `contact_type` is "Individual"
3. THEN copy the data from `member_number` to `external_id` for the matching internal id number.

I've tried a few variations of this, with different errors:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (external_id)
SELECT member_number 
FROM member_info
INNER JOIN test_table
ON memberinfo.entity_id=test_table.id
WHERE test_table.external_id IS NULL AND test_table.contact_type = "Individual"
```

Do I even really need the INNER JOIN on this? And I know the WHERE statement usually refers to the table you're pulling from, not the one you're inserting to, but I can't remember the right way to do this.

Comment: What's the table structure for test_table? and what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Oops, meant to include that. The test_table is a clone of the civicrm_contacts table, quite a few fields that are mostly varchar; The error is: #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'UI_external_identifier'

Comment: Nevermind.... I finally tracked down the "duplicate entry" it was referring to, turns out there were 2 "0" values in with the NULLS. Don't know why the other errors popped up, but eventually got it to work. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

```
update test_table
set external_id = 
if(external_id = '' and contact_type = 'Individual', member_number,external_id)
```

Comment: This one didn't do the trick, but I like the simplicity and I'm sure this is on the right track. I'm still getting an error, "#1054 - Unknown column 'member_number' in 'field list'"